# Formik Default Values UseEffect Hook Does Not Load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am trying to set the initial values of a form in React.JS in the useEffect hook. The memo field fails to load any data. What is wrong with my code?

```js
 
     const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState<PurchaseOrderDto>();

 useEffect(() => {

        agent.PurchaseOrder.List(id).then((response) => {
            setInitialValues(response.data);
        });

}, []);
```

```html
return (
        <Formik
            enableReinitialize
            initialValues={ initialValues }
            onSubmit={async (values, { setErrors, setStatus, setSubmitting }) => {
                try {
                    
                } catch (error: any) {
                    const message = error.message || "Something went wrong";

                    setStatus({ success: false });
                    setErrors({ submit: message });
                    setSubmitting(false);
                }
            }}
        >
            {({
                errors,
                handleBlur,
                handleChange,
                handleSubmit,
                isSubmitting,
                touched,
                values,
            }) => (
                <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    {errors.submit && (
                        <Alert mt={2} mb={1} severity="warning">
                            {errors.submit}
                        </Alert>
                    )}

                    <TextField
                        type="text"
                        name="Memo"
                        label="Memo"
                        value={initialValues?.memo}
                        //error={Boolean(touched.Memo && errors.Memo)}
                        fullWidth
                        helperText={values?.memo && errors.memo}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        my={3}
                    />
```